# How do I get an instance Id of app engine front server?

Tags: google-app-engine

And is there a way to send a request directly to that server?

Answer (score 7):

Actually there is a way and it can be useful for pushing new data out to all instances of an application.

```
from google.appengine.api import modules
instance_id = modules.get_current_instance_id()
```

[ref: GAE Modules Docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/)

Comment: In Java I'm trying String `instanceId = System.getProperty( "INSTANCE_ID" );` but it returns null.  Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Tom: Hi Tom, in Java the instance ID is stored at AppEngine's environment attributes map. See my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/a/15111345/752918 for a code example.

Answer (score 1):

For what purpose?

If you want to test different versions, you can use traffic splitting https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/trafficsplitting

That is different versions though, and not a specific instance.

Comment: I wanted to see if it's possible to implement a long polling service. Chat like service. I need to know what instance the client is connected to so I can notify that instance.

Comment: see https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/channel/  . In general, using Channel API is a better choice than polling in situations where updates can't be predicted or scripted, such as when relaying information between human users or from events not generated systematically.

Comment: thanks. seems like a good solution. but it costs $1/10,000 channel opened. Need to do some math to see if this is a viable option.

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't.

Usually when someone asks something like this, they're headed in the wrong direction on app engine.  Frontend servers get started and shutdown all the time.  If you are designing anything that relies on a particular instance, you're doing it wrong.  You need to design requests that work no matter what instance they hit.

Consider using backends if you must do that.

Comment: It doesn't mean that there's no legitimate usage of this feature. This can be useful if I want to send a specific command for a particular instance, such as clearing my in-memory cache. I have opened a feature request for this in [here](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8031).

Answer (score 0):

I use Python and a datetime stamp to identify an instance. This instance id is set by appengine_config.py. To signal other instances I use a flag in memcache, which is checked by the `__init__` of my webapp2 request handler.
I use signals to other instances to flush the jinja environment and reload dynamic python code, because I could not find another way.

Here is an example of a memcache flag; signalling to reload all dynamic modules, which had been set by instance id: '2012-12-26 16:39:50.072000'

```
{ u'_all': { u'dyn_reloads_dt': datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 26, 16, 39, 59, 120000),
             u'setter_instance': '2012-12-26 16:39:50.072000'}}
```

And I starred the [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8031) from : Ibrahim Arief

Answer (score 0):

With the advent of [Modules](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/), you can get the current instance id in [a more elegant way](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/modules/ModulesService#getCurrentInstanceId%28%29):

`ModulesServiceFactory.getModulesService().getCurrentInstanceId()`

Also, according to [this doc](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/routing#addressing_instances), you can route requests specifically to a particular instance by using a URL like

`http://instance.version.module.app-id.appspot.com`

Note that you need to replace the dot with `-dot-` to suppress the SSL certificate warning your web client may be complaining about:

`http://instance-dot-version-dot-module-dot-app-id.appspot.com`