# App Engine Instance ID

Tags: google-app-engine

Is it possible to get info on what instance you're running on? I want to output just a simple identifier for which instance the code is currently running on for logging purposes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get an instance Id of app engine front server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731719/how-do-i-get-an-instance-id-of-app-engine-front-server)

Comment: @PaulC: Not really a duplicate, the body of that question relates to the way to forward a request to a specific app engine frontend server.

Comment: Sure, the first answer says this though: app_instance_id = os.environ.get('INSTANCE_ID')  which is what I think the OP needs to know.

Comment: @PaulC: Ah yes, you are right, mea culpa, I didn't know that code was the Python equivalent. I think my answer still stands as the Java implementation of the Python code.

Comment: I guess the next person along has both answers availalbe, which is after all all that really matters :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there is no language tag, and seeing your profile history, I assume you are using GAE/J?

In that case, the instance ID information is embedded in one of the environment attributes that you could get via `ApiProxy.getCurrentEnvironment()` method. You could then extract the instance id from the resulting map using key `BackendService.INSTANCE_ID_ENV_ATTRIBUTE`.

Even though the key is stored in BackendService, this approach will also work for frontend instances. So in summary, the following code would fetch the instance ID for you:

```
String tInstanceId = ApiProxy.getCurrentEnvironment()
                             .getAttributes()
                             .get( BackendService.INSTANCE_ID_ENV_ATTRIBUTE )
                             .toString();
```

Please keep in mind that this approach is quite undocumented by Google, and might subject to change without warning in the future. But since your use case is only for logging, I think it would be sufficient for now.

Answer (score 1):

With the advent of [Modules](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/), you can get the current instance id in [a more elegant way](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/modules/ModulesService#getCurrentInstanceId%28%29):

`ModulesServiceFactory.getModulesService().getCurrentInstanceId()`

Answer (score 1):

Even better, you should wrap the call in a try catch so that it will work correctly locally too.

Import this

```
import com.google.appengine.api.modules.ModulesException;
import com.google.appengine.api.modules.ModulesServiceFactory;
```

Then your method can run this

```
String instanceId = "unknown";
try{
    instanceId = ModulesServiceFactory.getModulesService().getCurrentInstanceId();
} catch (ModulesException e){
    instanceId = e.getMessage();
}
```

Without the try catch, you will get some nasty errors when running locally.

I have found this super useful for debugging when using endpoints mixed with pub-sub and other bits to try to determine why some things work differently and to determine if it is related to new instances.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about before, but today in 2021 the system environment variable `GAE_INSTANCE` appears to contain the instance id:

```
instanceId = System.getenv("GAE_INSTANCE")
```

Comment: Yeah. Long time ago. Things have changed I'm sure.